# How to run R program script from console

Tags: r

Hi friends I am new to R programming. I dont know how to run a R programming script from console. I have created a test.R file and saved in d:|rpro folder and changed the directory path. In console i am trying to run the script by the command

> ? Rscript test.R

but i am getting the error as 
      Error: unexpected symbol in "? Rscript test.R"
Please help me

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506007/running-r-code-from-command-line-windows

Comment: You should not type `?` in front of your command. `Rscript test.R` does the trick.

Comment: > Rscript test.R
Error: unexpected symbol in "Rscript test.R"

Comment: If I type the command source("test.R") it is showing the output.

Comment: I am just learning the R programming for beginners and executing the program given. There it is given to use Rscript to run the program. But it was showing the above error. I am using the R in windows-8

Comment: 'Rscript test.R'  should be entered at the operating system command prompt, not inside R.

Comment: Is  source("test.R") is the correct way to execute the program

Answer (score 4):

From comments:

Try the following command

```
source("test.R")
```

Make sure you set the working directory correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by

```
R CMD BATCH your_script.R your_script.log
```

your_script.R requires full path to r script  and your_script.log will store the logs

Comment: This is from the command line, not the 'R console' as the author intended; however it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a windows box, then you should search for the Rscript.exe to run your .R file from the command prompt.
For example here's a file that I created to print the first 10 numbers of a fibonacci series and I have run it on the Windows command prompt

c:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin>Rscript c:\users\anand_hs\Documents\fib.R
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 8
[1] 13
[1] 21
[1] 34

### c:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin>

[edit-September 10, 2018]
You can also use the source() function from within the R console to load your .R file (assuming you're trying to access functions from within a script file).
Example:

> source('C:/Users/anand/andybash/FuncPractice.R')

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The commands 'Rscript test.R' should be entered at the operating system command prompt, not inside R console.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an Rscript file in some directory with the appropriate .R designator which R console can "see" the just click the R symbol (second from left) at the top of the console

Comment: The OP required the correct syntax for running a script in the console. While your suggestion may work, it does not answer the OP's specific question.